# Query slow on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a server with 20 clients. If I don't use a client for 1 day, the result of query arrives after 2:30 minutes (over 1000 rows). After the execution of 5/6 queries, the result arrives after few seconds.

I think it's a scheduling problem of SQL Server. How can I resolve?

Thanks

UPDATE

this is the query

```
Select * from  [WWALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmConsolidated]
Where Critico = 1 AND ApprovatoQA = 0 
AND InAttesaDiRiconoscimento Like '%param1%' 
AND (Tipo Like '%param2%') AND Area Like '%param3%'
AND Nome Like '%%param4%%' AND Descrizione Like '%%param5%%'
AND (([Dataora Scatto] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param6',105))
AND ([Dataora Scatto] <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param7',105))
OR( ([Dataora Rientro] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param6',105))
AND ([Dataora Rientro] <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param7',105))  )
OR(  ([Dataora PresoInCarico] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param6',105))
AND ([Dataora PresoInCarico] <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'param7',105))  ))
ORDER BY AlarmID DESC
```

Comment: Caching nothing special

Comment: then, the problem is in the query, right?

Comment: @chianta No, the problem is the first time the query is run, its pulling data from disk storage - after a few runs, the data is in memory, so it runs faster.   Look into cache tuning and binding to resolve this.

Comment: A few seconds to retrieve 1,000 rows sounds like there are some MAJOR problems with your query unless the tables are millions and millions of rows. 1,000 rows should be able to be retrieved nearly instantly most of the time. I agree that caching is obviously part of the problem but it sounds that the query itself could use some tuning.

Comment: But since no real details about the query are known, we are just guessing.

Comment: Right off the bat, using leading wildcards in searches will result in poor performance as the server has to scan each row and is unable to use indices on those columns, if they exist.

Comment: Thanks to all,  I will optimize the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is a normal SQL Server caching behavior.

More information about MSSQL Server caching mechanisms [you can find here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx)

It's impossible to tell you anything else without knowing the background (example sql queries, health status of your sql server machine and actual db data structure)

**UPDATE:**

Your query is probably so badly optimized, that is actually a miracle it's only 2:30

```
SELECT *

LIKE '%%*%%'

ORDER BY
```

Comment: Thanks, I will optimize the query

Comment: You can see an execution plan for your query in SQL Management Studio.

Use table aliases and SELECT only these columns, that you really need to select. Make sure that you are ORDERING a column with an index on that column (or clustered primary key). Using LIKE with a first character '%' is not good idea, because execution plan will automatically do full seek, without using any index at all.

Or you can select only some base data into temporary table, then create an index on those columns, filter them by LIKE and then join again full data on these IDs